# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::salarylevels does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between users and salary_levels. All I have is an error stating Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::salarylevels does not exist. The salarylevels method is defined under User model. How could this happen?

**User Model:**

```
 public function salarylevels(){
   
    return $this->belongsToMany(SalaryLevel::class)->withPivot(['leave_entitlement']);

   }
```

**SalaryLevel:**

```
 public function users(){

  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['leave_entitlement']);

}
```

**Store Method:**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $users = User::where('id',$request->input('employee_id', []))->get();

    
    $Ids = [
       1 => ['leave_entitlement' => '30'],
       3 => ['leave_entitlement' => '22']
     ];

    $users->salarylevels()->sync($Ids);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `$users->salaryLevels()` is not correct. `$users` is a `Collection` because you have done:

> $users = User::where('id', $request->input('employee_id', []))->get();

`get()` returns a `Collection`, so you should do:

```php
$users = User::where('id', $request->input('employee_id', []))->first();
```